# using dll extention instead of the standard aspx

Tags: asp.net

I am replacing an existing web application, that all it's requests go through a url:
www.something.com/scripts/xxx.dll?args

I created my own aspx page that handles these requests and it is called:
www.something.com/scripts/xxx.aspx?args

My problem is that there are many existing links, from other website that refer to the xxx.dll?args url.

Can I create my own dll in .net that will receive the xxx.dll?args requests and process them?
This isn't a simple redirect, because I also need the args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation I did the following.

Change the web.config, to make sure all requests go through my code by adding the following code:

```
 ...<system.webServer>
  <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">...
```

Added a global.asax file to the web project, and within it wrote the following code:

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Path.EndsWith("xxx.dll",
         StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            Context.RewritePath("/scripts/xxx.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to rather use [Url Rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)